# Changing program to work with multiple lines

Tags: c, function, if-statement

I have a program. It's a simple calculator. It evaluates numbers which are given in form  `1 + 3`. I have a problem with it. I need to modify program to work with multiple lines. I should look like this:

```
1 + 3  //input 
1 * 9  //input in another line
6 / 2  //input in another line
ctrl+z

result first 
result second
result third
```

But I dont know how to modify it. I tried diffrend ways and all fails. I have also problem with dividing by 0. I'm not sure how to make exception about it.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tools.h"

int main(void) {
    char string[100];
    int result;
    result = InterCalc(string, sizeof(string));
    Calc(result, string);
    return 0;
}
```

tools.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include "tools.h"

static float f1, f2;
static char op;

int isValidExpression(const char *str)
{
    int res;
    char ops[10];
    res=sscanf(str, "%f %s %f", &f1, ops, &f2);
    if (res==3) {
        if (ops[0]=='+' || ops[0]=='-' || ops[0]=='^' || ops[0]=='*' || ops[0]=='/')
            {
                op=ops[0];
                return 1;
            }
            else return 0;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int getOperator()
{
    return(op);
}

float getFstOperand()
{
    return(f1);
}

float getSecOperand()
{
    return(f2);
}

float getExprValue(void) {
    switch (getOperator()) {
    case '+':
        return getFstOperand() + getSecOperand();
    case '-':
        return getFstOperand() - getSecOperand();
    case '/':
        return getFstOperand() / getSecOperand();
    case '*':
        return getFstOperand() * getSecOperand();
    case '^':
        return pow(getFstOperand(), getSecOperand());
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}

int InterCalc(char *my_string, size_t size) {
    if (fgets(my_string, size, stdin) == NULL ||  strcmp(my_string, "exit\n") == 0) {
        printf("Program ended\n");
        return 0;
    } else
    if (isValidExpression(my_string) == 0) {
        printf("Expression error\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

void Calc(int a, char *str)
{
    float calculation_value;
        if (a==1) {
            calculation_value = getExprValue();
            printf("The result of %s is %f.\n", str, calculation_value);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to buffer everything until all lines are read? For most purposes it is better to read a line, output the result and iterate that until EOF. Can you elaborate why this is not possible with your application?

Comment: As @Ctx said, it is not at all necessary in most cases. And also if the inputs are known before hand, you can paste the entire input sequence in the console. In that case the input comes first and then the outputs.

Comment: @Ctx It's a good idea. I wonder how could I implement this in my program. I should sscanf function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 2D-array of your string to accept multiple expressions, like:

```
char string[10][200];
```

Loop over your array of expression and evaluate using your evaluations functions and store your results in any 1D array.

To make a zero divide check, you can make check in your `isValidExpression()` and return an error `if ops[0]=='/' and f2==0`.